# Built in function undefined in imported function

Tags: python-3.x, import

I think I miss something important in the way imports work in Python, and I couldn't find a solution. I reduced the problem to its simple expression :
I have two files :
*test_fonctions.py*

```
def fonction2(x):
    return sqrt(x)
```

*test_preambule.py*

```
from math import sqrt
```

these files are placed in a subfolder called lib, containing as well an empty file called **init**.py

when I run this code in my main file :

```
exec(open("lib/test_preambule.py").read())
from lib.test_fonctions import *

print(sqrt(5))
print(fonction2(5))
```

sqrt works fine, but the second function yields to :

File "....\Tests\lib\test_fonctions.py", line 2, in fonction2
return sqrt(x)
NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined

Undefined but defined, listed as builtin_function_or_method in the workspace...

What did I miss ?

(the real question is : "Is there a way to make my imports work properly?")

Answer (score 0):

I found a turnover by remplacing the import by an exec

```
exec(open('./lib/test_preambule.py').read())
exec(open('./lib/test_fonctions.py').read())
```

But if someone has an explanation, I'd be glad to hear it.